# how can I add n days to a date excluding National holidays odoo

Tags: odoo

how can I exclude national holidays ?
I used the code below to exclude Sundays

```html
    @api.depends('date_request', 'Nbr_days')
    def _compute_date_result(self):
 
        for record in self:
            business_days_to_add = record.Nbr_days
            current_date = fields.Datetime.from_string(record.date_request)
            while business_days_to_add > 0:
                current_date += timedelta(days=1)
                weekday = current_date.weekday()
                if weekday >= 6: 
                    continue
                business_days_to_add -= 1
            record.date_perform=current_date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since holidays normally span whole dates, you can do the following:

```py
holiday_dates = set([dt.date() for dt in Holidays])
# And a few lines later in your exclusion check
# while ...
    if weekday >= 6 or current_date.date() in holiday_dates: 
        continue
```

Comment: and should I change the Holidays every year?

Comment: If there are holidays that change dates, or when holidays are added/removed - then yes. Otherwise, you can just modify the code to compare the month and day part only.